# How fix external dependency missing jar with maven?

Tags: maven, build, maven-2

I'm kinf of noob with maven and I'm trying to attach an external jar to my project.
So I have a **x.jar** dependency in my **${project.basedir}\src\lib** folder which is required in my project.

When I run `mvn clean install`, it finishes successfully.
When I run `java -jar project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, I get the error
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

My pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>x.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>x</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/lib/x.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

How should I run maven or edit my pom in order to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Standard jars don't include dependencies and therefore cannot be run on command line unless you specify the full classpath.

So either build a `jar-with-dependencies` (maven assembly plugin or maven shade plugin), or list the dependencies explicitly.

Comment: I tried adding maven assembly plugin, but still don't work.
Maybe I should change anything else in the dependency?
Note: I have also tried using the complete path on ```<systemPath>```, but still don't work.
I'm running ```mvn clean install``` and then java -jar to execute the jar, which still gets the class not found.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I am not sure whether systemPath dependencies are added by default. SystemPath is deprecated.